# Read Mic volume

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm very very new on iPhone development.

I want to get mic volumen but I don't know how.

Is there any way to read mic volume?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "SpeakHere" sample code from Apple.  It has everything you need: [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802)

Comment: The volume is not constant. In voice memo app, VU meter gets constant (more or less).